# Async changes to properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

New to vuejs.

I have a vue with the following script (code shortened):

```
export default {
  mixins: [asyncStatuses],
  props: {
    value: { type: Object }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      statuses: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
      hasStatuses() {
          return this.statuses && this.statuses.length > 0;
      }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    // This is an async call
    this.getStatuses().then((response) => {
      this.statuses = response.data.statuses;
    });
  }
};
```

In my .vue file, I do something like this:

```
<div v-if="hasStatuses">
    <div>Show a list of statuses</div>
</div>
```

The problem is the `<div>` never shows up.  The statuses are loading correctly.  I put a debugger in the `computed.hasStatuses` but it never runs?

Can anyone explain to me how and why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks again!!

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. https://jsfiddle.net/eptwaa9f/ if you `console.log(response.data.statuses)` you get a non-empty array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is setting `self.statuses`, but `self` is not defined.

```
self.statuses = response.data.statuses
```

Just use `this`.

```
this.statuses = response.data.statuses
```

Comment: The code has been updated correctly.  The issue still exists.

Comment: After looking at code, fixing it and then for some reason having to restart all servers, it worked correctly.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Sean No problem :)